# Porque usar getElementById se o id está no window?

Tags: javascript, dom

Recentemente em meus estudo notei um objeto que manipulava o DOM do elemento que tinha o mesmo nome em seu *id*.

```js
teste.style.border = '1px solid #CCC';
teste.style.width = '500px';
teste.style.height = '50px';
```

```html
<div id="teste">
</div>
```

#### Dúvida

- Por que os *ids* vão para o *global space*?
- Se eu posso acessar o elemento direto por seu *id*, por que usar *getElementById*?

#### Nota

Objetos de nome composto são acessíveis no *window*

```js
window['teste-id_composto'].style.border = '1px solid #CCC';
window['teste-id_composto'].style.width = '500px';
window['teste-id_composto'].style.height = '50px';
```

```html
<div id="teste-id_composto">
</div>
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

O facto de elementos nomeados<sup>*</sup> fazerem parte das propriedades de `document` e/ou `window` é uma infelicidade, fruto de aplicações bem simples que havia há muitos anos, no inicio do DOM e JavaScript.

Infelizmente por serem usadas e alguns browsers as promoverem elas ainda existem para não quebrar código antigo, e são até prática comum. Ter referências a elementos nas propriedades de `document` ou `window` é muito má ideia, uma vez que ocupam o mesmo espaço que variáveis do código das aplicações que sejam corridas e podem ser "apagadas". Sim, declarar uma função ou variável no espaço global sobrescreve alguma propriedade que venha de um elemento nomeado que use o mesmo nome.

**Qual a solução segura para separar as àguas?**

**=**> usar `document.getElementById()` e/ou `document.querySelector()`

### O que diz a W3C?

A especificação de HTML 5.1 (12 abril de 2016) é bem clara aqui e recomenda não aceder a elementos nomeados, via `document` ou `window`. [Na especificação diz assim](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object):

> As a general rule, relying on this will lead to brittle code. Which IDs end up mapping to this API can vary over time, as new features are added to the Web platform, for example. Instead of this, use `document.getElementById()` or `document.querySelector()`.

Ou seja, *"em regra geral depender deste método (`window[id]`) gera código frágil. Em vêz desta tecnologia deve usar-se `document.getElementById()` ou `document.querySelector()`"*.

---

Nota:

> <sup>*</sup> - elementos nomeados (*named elements* é a designação que conheço em Inglês) são todos os elementos que têm o atributo `id` ou `name` definido.

Comment: Agora com essa nota da W3C digo que esta é a melhor resposta +1

Answer (score 30):

Antes de existirem padrões para o HTML, CSS e JavaScript quem definia isto eram os próprios browsers, ou seja cada browser tinha a sua maneira de fazer as coisas, exemplo disso era a maneira de obtêr os elementos do DOM:

- Internet Explorer 4 usavamos `document.all`
- Netscape4 usavamos `document.layers`

Estes eram os principais browsers do "mercado" e eram os que primeiro implementaram JavaScript (no InternetExplorer era chamado de JScript)

A partir da versão do *InternetExplorer 5.01* passou a ser suportado o `document.getElementById` e `document.getElementsByTagName`, o único que não funcionava no InternetExplorer era o `document.getElementsByTagName("*");`, que só passou a ser suportado no InternetExplorer 6, pra isso tínhamos que usar `document.all` ainda.

Os IDs por serem elementos "únicos" no InternetExplorer (apesar de alguns desenvolvedores repetirem eles, o que é um equivoco) passavam a ser acessíveis diretamente nas referencias das variáveis globais que no JavaScript pra navegadores é o objeto `window`, isso desde que o DOM estivesse carregado e a variável não tivesse sido declarada.

O InternetExplorer manteve essa característica pra poder manter a compatibilidade com sites que tinham sido feito pra versões anteriores, alguns navegadores importaram tal característica pra tentar manter a compatibilidade

Na época era muito comum acusar o navegador por não funcionar em determinado site, quando o problema na verdade era no script, então muitos desenvolvedores de motores se viam obrigados a colocar essas peculiaridades nos próprios motores.

No Firefox por exemplo o `document.layers` ainda era suportado, mas emitia um *warning* no console avisando que ele seria removido, diferentemente o InternetExplorer manteve muitas coisas, como o `document.all` (esse as vezes gera uma lista de DOM diferente do `document.getElementsByTagName("*");`).

Existiu um motor chamado [iCab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICab) (até a versão 3 do navegador do qual seu motor nome também se chamava iCab, na versão 4 em diante passou a usar Webkit e Cocoa API) para macOS que tinha funcionalidades semelhantes ao do IE4 como `document.all`, isso era uma maneira de manter a compatibilidade com sites feitos pra Internet Explorer.

**É provável** (não tem nada discutido, é apenas uma suposição) que com a evolução dos navegadores e "normas" do [ECMAScript](http://ecma-international.org/memento/TC39.htm) o `window` gerar uma variável que represente um elemento por id automaticamente seja removido um dia e só seja mantido o que é realmente necessário, ou seja se usar algo como `window.meuElemento`, isto poderá falhar no futuro.

Também não recomendo usar a referencia da ID devido aos conflitos com variáveis que podem ter sido definidas e que tenham o mesmo nome do `id` (isto é um problema que já pode ocorrer e não depende do futuro).

Note que existem outras propriedades pra obter elementos DOM como:

- [`document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms)

  Obtém formulários pelo index como `document.forms[0]`
- [`document.embeds`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/embeds)

  Obtém elementos `<embed>` pelo index como `document.embeds[0]`
- [`window.frames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames)

  Obtém elementos `<frame>` e `<iframe>` pelo index como `window.frames[0]`, note que `window.frames` não retorna o elemento DOM do (i)frame e sim o objeto `window` de dentro dele, isto `window.frames[0]` então seria o mesmo que fazer isto `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow`

Comment: Pode se disser que é um complemento histórico para a resposta de @Sergio. Muito interessante.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Pode ser =)

Answer (score 4):

A diferença é pequena, está mais no tempo de processamento. O "document" já é um elemento renderizado pelo Dom, neste sentido,quando você usa `getElementById` você está capturando a id do elemento renderizado propriamente dito, e não ocorrerá erro se o elemento não existir no seu documento. O que torna a propriedade mais segura de não dar um erro, enquanto, no `window['id_nome']`, é capturado pela estrutura da sua janela global, o que acontece neste caso, é que você captura do array da janela... Não há muita diferença em si, mas no caso do `window['id_nome']`, pode ocorrer erro, principalmente se você digitar o índice erroneamente, ou tentar localizar algo que não exista no window, também depende muito do comportamento da janela e do tipo de navegador, o IE é meio falho nesse quesito. Pois se não tiver um tratamento adequado, em algum momento, poderia não encontrar o índice do array, mas nada que não possa ser resolvido conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
if (window['id_name']) {
    var el = window['id_name'];
}
```

**PS:** Só tome cuidado com uso de palavras reservadas da janela.

Comment: Olá Ivan, poderia explicar exatamente aonde o IE é falho? Desculpe falar, mas sobre a parte que você afirma que `window['id_nome']` pode causar erro se o elemento não existir e o `getElementById` não, me parece errado em ambos casos podem ocorrer falhas, `window['id_nome']` se não existir o elemento vai retornar apenas `undefined` e `document.getElementById('id_nome')` retornará `null`. O erro pode ocorrer em ambos, já que retornariam undefined e null. É apenas uma critica construtiva visando que possivelmente você possa melhorar sua resposta. ;)

Comment: Uma forma de evitar este erro é usando: `window.onload = function() { ... }`, undefined é diferente de null, então, o erro, é exatamente essa a diferença, undefined é um elemento não definido, o que podemos considerar um erro de lógica, se algo esperado (um array da janela) estaria definido, não teria porque retornar undefined. (isso é tratado como um erro).

Comment: Caro Ivan, Isso de undefined e null que citei é outra coisa, eu disse que vai retornar, seja diferente null ou undefined, eu se como evitar isso (por exemplo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137881/3635), a questão que não dá para entender é a parte que vc fala do IE ser falho, mas é algo que ficou dificil de entender aonde exatamente é isto, eu queria entender isto que vc citou ;)

Comment: É que no IE, o dom é processado com mais lentidão... por isso falha.

Comment: Isso é um equívoco, fez algum teste de benchmark? Sabe que é para isto que existem eventos como DOMContentLoaded ou a propriedade document.readyState, ser um motor de processamento ou renderização mais lento não significa falha alguma. Aliás, se um site não for em "buffer" e for lento, o DOM vai demorar de processar de qualquer forma, seja Chrome, FF, IE, Safari.

Comment: Cara eu não gosto do IE, ele trava pra caramba, independente disso, eu já fiz vários testes, e vou te dizer, ele não é estável, principalmente quando você trabalha com eventos e captura de elementos do dom, trava pra caramba, e não estou falando das novas arquiteturas, do edge por exemplo que é totalmente diferente, mas dos modelos mais antigos, e muitas vezes ele trava a ponto de fechar o navegador... eu não preciso testar o PC pra saber que o problema é do navegador, quando o meu PC tem todos os requisitos necessários para rodar e não ter o mesmo comportamento com demais nevegadores.

Comment: E hoje em nem uso mais PC, só mac.

Comment: Por anos o IE foi usado, se teve problemas assim ou simplesmente não sabia usar bem o JS e tinha uma série de navbars instalados (coisas comuns no IE) ou tinha problema de fato com os computadores, ele não era uma "beleza", mas não implicava em nada do que conversamos e nem do que é o assunto da pergunta.