# Existe algum equivalente de "$(document).ready()" com Javascript puro?

Tags: javascript

No jQuery, precisamos utilizar `$(document).ready()` para saber se o documento foi carregado e, então, com segurança executarmos o nosso script jQuery.

Segundo a documentação do jQuery

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you.

Tradução:

> A página não pode ser manipulada com segurança até que o documento está "pronto". jQuery detecta esse estado de prontidão para você.

Agora, no caso do Javascript puro, sem jQuery ou nenhum outro framework, existe alguma maneira de detectar que o documento foi carregado, para ter a mesma garantia que temos com `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Veja esse outro tópico [pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the).

Comment: Existe um site específico sobre esse assunto: [YouMightNotNeedJQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ready).

Comment: Gostei @renan :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O que o [jQuery faz](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/305f193aa57014dc7d8fa0739a3fefd47166cd44/src/core/ready.js) é lêr a propriedade `document.readyState` quando a página carrega, e caso ainda não esteja carregada escuta um dos eventos `load` ou `DOMContentLoad`. O primeiro evento a ser chamado dispara o `ready`.

Na prática simplificando seria assim ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/no6gt4mL/)):

```
function ready() {
    // quando esta função correr o DOM está acessível
}

function completed() {
    document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", completed);
    window.removeEventListener("load", completed);
    ready();
}

if (document.readyState === "complete" ||
    (document.readyState !== "loading" && !document.documentElement.doScroll)) {
    ready(); // está pronto!
} else { // ainda não está pronto...
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", completed);
    window.addEventListener("load", completed);
}
```

O IE 8 tinha um bug com o scroll e por isso essa linha que refere o Scroll. Há um artigo muito bom sobre isso ([link](http://javascript.nwbox.com/IEContentLoaded/)), mas como o IE8 já não é suportado pode remover-se.

A [versão do MooTools](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Utilities/DOMReady.js) é parecida, um pouco mais complexa e por isso mais completa, e usa o mecanismo interno de eventos do MooTools. Toma ainda em conta browsers mais antigos que não têm `readystatechange`. Mas isso já não interessa nos tempos de hoje.

---

**Para browsers modernos** pode fazer-se assim ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/x2hy4rr6/1/)):

```
var domReady = function(ready) {
    if (document.readyState != 'loading') return ready();
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);
    function _ready() {
        document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);
        ready();
    }
}
```

**Para browsers antigos** poder-se-ia fazer assim ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/x2hy4rr6/)), mantendo a coisa simples:

```
var domReady = function(ready) {
    var attacher = document.addEventListener ? {
        add: 'addEventListener',
        remove: 'removeEventListener'
    } : {
        add: 'attachEvent',
        remove: 'detachEvent'
    };

    function completed() {
        document[attacher.remove]("DOMContentLoaded", completed);
        window[attacher.remove]("load", completed);
        ready();
    }

    if (document.readyState === "complete" ||
        (document.readyState !== "loading" && !document.documentElement.doScroll)) {
        ready(); // está pronto!
    } else { // ainda não está pronto...
        document[attacher.add]("DOMContentLoaded", completed);
        window[attacher.add]("load", completed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Algumas versões abaixo do IE 9 também não funcionarão com `addEventListener`, por isso dá para substituir o método por `attachEvent` caso existir (uma nota caso alguém se preocupar com o suporte dos navegadores).

Comment: @KlaiderKlai verdade, fica aqui ([link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.12.4/src/core/ready.js#L67-L76)) a versão do jQuery para browsers antigos, tendo em conta esse aspeto. Outra possibilidade seria usar `window.onload = function(){ready();}` para o meu exemplo em cima, mas isso também para browsers muito antigos, por isso não junto à resposta, fica aqui.

Comment: @KlaiderKlai tem razão, um polyfill cairia bem

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento juntei uma versão para browsers antigos.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento força.

Comment: Agora que percebi, document.readyState só tem 3 valores possíveis, e eu usando regex a toa (`/^(interactive|complete)$/`). Vivendo e aprendendo :D

Comment: @Sergio só pra constar, apesar de hoje não fazer mais diferenças nos navegadores modernos, o `doScroll` é uma função e não uma propriedade, eu queria atualizar seu código, mas a implementação do mesmo requer try/catch, então prefiro não modificar sua lógica, mas se puder ajustar fica melhor. Obrigado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento exato. Daí o código ter `!` para converter num booleano se esse método está presente no `documentElement`, sem o invocar.

Comment: Acho que entendi, Então a intenção é que no IE só execute via load e se suportar via DOMContentLoaded?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento no IE8 (o que implica não ter `.doScroll`) tudo o que seja diferente de `loading` é uma página caregada.

Comment: @Sergio entendo, obrigado.

Answer (score 6):

Pra ficar semelhante ao funcionamento do jQuery temos que adicionar uma checagem extra acaso.

- Note que `interactive` não funciona bem no IE então usei `doScroll`
- Note que `document.readyState` não é suportado por alguns navegadores, então mantive o onload como um "fallback"
- Pra usar `document.readyState` é necessário `setInterval` ou `setTimeout`
- A variavel `isReady` serve pra evitar rodar um script todo acaso já esteja carregado (também evitando problemas em navegadores sem suporte ao `document.readyState`)
- O `(function () {` serve pra isolar a variavel `isReady` ficando dentro do escopo
- O evento `DOMContentLoaded` é acionado quando o documento inicial HTML foi completamente carregado e analisado, sem aguardar por folhas de estilo, imagens, e subframes para encerrar o carregamento, mas não é suportado por alguns navegadores mais antigos, como IE8
- No script abaixo o `DOMContentLoaded` corre paralelamente com as demais funções ou seja quem terminar primeiro irá disparar o callback.
- O evento `load` no `window` é uma garantia acaso tudo falhar ou for um navegador sem suporte algum (é bem raro)

O código ficaria assim:

```js
(function (w, d) {
    var isReady = false;

    w.domReady = function(callback)
    {
        /*
        Se a página já estiver carregada e já tiver rodado alguma vez
        o window.domReay então esta if evita fazer registro de eventos
        ou testes desnecessários, assim otimizando o tempo de resposta
        */
        if (isReady) {
             callback();
             return;
        }

        var done = false;
    
        var doc = d.documentElement;
    
        var attacher = d.addEventListener ? {
            add: 'addEventListener',
            remove: 'removeEventListener'
        } : {
            add: 'attachEvent',
            remove: 'detachEvent'
        };
    
        function completed() {

            /*
            A variável done impede que o script seja executado duas vezes
            */
            if (done) { return; }

            done = true;
            isReady = true;
    
            d[attacher.remove]("DOMContentLoaded", completed);
            w[attacher.remove]("load", completed);
            callback();
        };
    
        if (d.readyState === "complete") {
            /*Se o navegador suportar readyState e a página já estiver carregada*/
            completed();
        } else if (doc.doScroll) {

            /*interactive para IE8 não funciona bem, doScroll é um fallback para IE8*/

            (function doScrollTest() {
                try {
                    doc.doScroll('left');
                    completed();
                } catch(e) {
                    setTimeout(doScrollTest, 50);
                }
            })();
        } else if (d.readyState) {

            /*Checa se é interactive ou completed*/

            (function readyStateTest() {
                if (d.readyState !== "loading") {
                    completed();
                } else {
                    setTimeout(readyStateTest, 50);
                }
            })();
        }
    
        d[attacher.add]("DOMContentLoaded", completed);
        w[attacher.add]("load", completed);
    };
})(window, document);

//Usando:
domReady(function() {
    console.log("ready");
});

domReady(function() {
    console.log("olá mundo");
});

domReady(function() {
    domReady(function() {
        console.log("domReady dentro de domReady");
    });
});

window.onload = function () {
    domReady(function() {
       console.log("domReady dentro de Onload");
    });
};
```

Comment: Boa, `+1`, para browsers antigos fica aqui uma boa versão também.

Answer (score 3):

Você também pode usar as tags de script no fim do body, como mostrado no código abaixo. Com o script dentro do body o código só será executado quando o body for carregado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        alert('A página foi carregada!');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Acho que `window.onload` equivale ao `$(window).load()`, não ao `ready`.

Comment: Tirando a parte "window.onload, como mostrada acima é o equivalente ao $(document).ready() do jQuery" que eu discordo, o resto da dica esta excelente André, sim colocar o script antes do `</body>` e se colocar tudo dentro de um unico .js ainda poderá usar async o que ajuda a acelerar a renderização. Parabéns, só remove o trecho que eu citei.