# Por que o Javascript não encontra uma tag da página?

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma dúvida simples:

Por que meu `alert` não exibe o valor do atributo `name` do botão? Estranhamente se eu inserir o código javascript após a tag `<button>` o alerta funciona normalmente. Segue o código que não funciona:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x = document.getElementById('a').name;
        function aoba() {
            alert(x);
        };
    </script>
    <body>
        <button id="a" value="b" onClick="aoba()" name="botão"> BOTÃO 1 </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podes [edit] a pergunta com o HTML que nós ajudamos a formatar. Como está é dificil ler o código...

Comment: Se colocares esse `var x = document.getElementById('a').name;` no final do body, ou esse JavaScript todo dentro de `window.onload = function(){ ... }` isso já ia funcionar

Comment: Obrigado  pela ajuda, acho que entendi o funcionamento da modo de carregamento do DOM.

Comment: Ótimo. Se quiseres podes marcar uma das respostas como aceite. Até breve.

Comment: @DanielDeSantanaSforzim, Se alguma resposta resolveu o seu problema, você pode clicar no **V** ao lado da resposta e marcar sua pergunta como respondida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

voce pode usar o seguinte codigo que acho que vai funcionar

```
<body onload="aoba()">
```

pode ter certeza que irá funcionar, pois voce esta tentando carregar a variavel antes do DOM ser criado, ai no caso ela nao existe ainda, mas com esse trecho de codigo voce vai fazer com que, assim que o DOM seja criado ele carregue o script.

abrsss

Answer (score 2):

O JavaScript acessa o HTML atravéz do DOM, que é uma representação do HTML em JavaScript. O que acontece é que o DOM ainda não está pronto/interpretado quando corres o teu código. Aliás no momento em que a tag `head` é lida `document` ainda não está acessível ao JavaScript.

Assim tens de colocar o teu código depois do Browser ler o HTML que queres. Podes fazer isso colocando o JavaScript no final da página, antes do fecho da tag `body` ou colocar esse script dentro de uma função que é chamada depois da página carregar (e neste caso pode estar dentro do `head` como está agora):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var x = document.getElementById('a').name;
    function aoba(){
        alert(x);
    };
}
```

Essa [função que corre quando o DOM está carregado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137853/129) pode ser mais complexa, caso necessário. Mas para o exemplo `window.onload` serve bem.

__

Nota, reparei agora que a tua tag `script` não está nem dentro do `body` nem do `head`. Tem de estar dentro de um deles.

Comment: Obrigado  pela ajuda, acho que entendi o funcionamento da modo de carregamento do DOM.

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece no seu código é que você está capturando o `name` do seu botão, antes dele ser criado na arvore **[DOM](http://tableless.com.br/tenha-o-dom/)**. Para resolver isso, a sua *Tag* `script` deve ficar abaixo do botão.

```
<button id="a" value="b" onClick="aoba()" name="botão"> BOTÃO 1 </button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var x = document.getElementById('a').name;

 function aoba(){alert(x);}; 

</script>
```

Pode também, capturar o `name` dentro do método a ser chamado, isso resolve o problema

```
function aoba(){
    var x = document.getElementById('a').name;
    alert(x);
}
```

E pelo evento `onload` da sua janela.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x;

    function aoba(){alert(x);};

    window.onload = function(){ // acrescenta o name em x quando a pagina terminar se ser carregada.
        x = document.getElementById('a').name;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado  pela ajuda, acho que entendi o funcionamento da modo de carregamento do DOM.