# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando utilizar no meu projeto o `scrollleft` com o botão, ele funciona normal no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oe0uwxn0/)

Porém quando coloco no meu projeto ele me retorna este erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null.

Comment: Facil, so chamar o seu arquivo "js" no fim da pagina html </body> <script src="SEUARQUIVO.js"></script> </HTML>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Provavelmente no script na sua máquina você não usou `window.onload` ou `DOMContentLoaded`, no jsfiddle funciona porque o script é executado depois do DOM carregar, veja como esta no seu *jsfiddle*:

[image: configuração do jsfiddle]

Então para ajustar pode fazer algo como:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var mover = document.getElementById("mover");
    var painel = document.getElementById("painel");

    mover.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      painel.scrollLeft += 100;
    });
};
```

Outra maneira com `onload` seria:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var mover = document.getElementById("mover");
    var painel = document.getElementById("painel");

    mover.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      painel.scrollLeft += 100;
    });
});
```

> O `addEventListener` pode torna um pouco mais fácil o uso de múltiplas funções com um mesmo tipo de evento

Ou com algo mais rápido:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var mover = document.getElementById("mover");
    var painel = document.getElementById("painel");

    mover.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      painel.scrollLeft += 100;
    });
});
```

A diferença de `onload` e `DOMContentLoaded` você pode ver aqui:

- [Qual a diferença entre $(document).ready() e window.onload?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182797/3635)

### Alternativa para navegadores antigos

Se necessitar de algo que faça o mesmo efeito do `DOMContentLoaded` para navegadores antigos você pode experimentar este exemplo:

- [Existe algum equivalente de “$(document).ready()” com Javascript puro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137881/3635)

Comment: Obrigado.. Funcionou PERFEITAMENTE, ERA ISSO QUE EU QUERIA. Obrigado.

Comment: Guilherme, como posso reproduzir essa primeira imagem que postou nessa resposta ?

Ultlizei a solução "window.onload" em meu código e funcionou perfeitamente. Isso significa que todo meu js deverá estar dentro do onload ?
Isso acontece porque o js está sendo carregado antes da pagina ?

Comment: @RailanePassos deverá estar dentro do onload se precisar manipular o DOM/HTML, mas não precisa ser o onload, como eu expliquei na resposta, o DOMContentLoaded será mais rapido pq só vai esperar a página carregar e não vai esperar imagens e videos e outras coisas, então você já vai poder pegar os elementos HTML

Comment: Obrigada Guilherme !