# Enviar uma string nome via post usando javascript

Tags: javascript, json, xml, post, xmlhttprequest

Boa noite, estou tentando enviar apenas nome para o servidor, mas toda vez que passo a string chega ao servidor como "nome:", aqui esta a maneira como estou tentando:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
            var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
            btn.addEventListener("click", function(){

                var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var jsObj = {nome: "Test"};
                var sendData = JSON.stringfy(jsObj);

                req.open('POST', 'https://url.com');
                req.Send(sendData);

            });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="btn">Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma correta de se escrever os dados json no seu caso seria

```
var jsObj = {"nome": "Test"};
```

Veja que nome fora de aspas seria uma variavel, mas no seu caso é o nome do campo que receberá o conteúdo "Test".

Answer (score 1):

Tem muitos erros, até mesmo o w3schools que é uma fonte que nunca recomendo tem exemplos prontos para você saber como fazer que já dariam uma boa noção, sinceramente espero que não entenda como uma critica, mas como dicas, teu script esta bem errado

Primeiro que `XMLHttpRequest` de forma síncrona é uma maneira de ruim de usar, um porque congela o navegador dependendo do tempo da resposta e outra que é algo que provavelmente em breve não vai funcionar no processo principal, somente com *Web Worker* (não tem data prevista, mas é possivel), o ideial é usar callbacks, aliais javascript vive de callbacks, não há mal algum em aprender o que é quase um requisito obrigatório para esta linguagem, ainda mais em front-end (sim existe JavaScript para back-end, mas ai é outra história e não quero fugir do tópico principal)

Para resumir isto é sincrono, não use:

```
req.open('POST', 'https://url.com');
```

Isto é assincrono (é preferivel):

```
req.open('POST', 'https://url.com', true);
```

Segundo problema, JavaScript é case-sensitive, então isto esta errado:

```
req.Send(sendData);
```

Deveria ser:

```
req.send(sendData);
```

Agora sobre como pegar JSON no lado do servidor, creio que você usa PHP (pelo que vi em suas outras perguntas) então use o `php://input` para isto, exemplo:

```
<?php
$dados = file_get_contents('php://input');

if ($dados) {
    $json = json_decode($dados, true);

    if ($json) {
       $nome = $json['nome'];
       echo 'nome:', $nome;
    }
}
```

Também é necessário ou colocar o script no final da página ou então usar:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {});
```

Faça assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var jsObj = {nome: "Test"};
        var sendData = JSON.stringfy(jsObj);

        req.open('POST', 'https://url.com/pagina.php', true);

        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (req.readyState != 4) return; //Ignora o resto enquanto readyState é diferente de 4 (4 = completo)

            if (req.status == 200) { //Resposta http padrão do PHP, afirma que esta tudo ok
                alert(req.responseText);//Exibe a resposta HTTP
            } else {
                alert("Erro HTTP ou conexão: " + req.status);//Exibe o código de erro HTTP ou um código de erro como "0" ou um outro numer (geralmente em IE) sobre problemas de conexão
            }
        };

        req.send(sendData);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="btn">Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta amigo, mas não estou usando php, na verdade estou usando heroku como servidor

Comment: @PublioElon o exemplo em PHP é só um exemplo mesmo, heroku usa php, python, ruby on rails, vc pode adaptar de qualquer forma, heroku não é linguagem é só o servidor.

Comment: perfeitamente amigo, mas a parte de pegar o que foi enviado esta feito, o problema esta na parte de envio

Comment: @PublioElon então, testou o código de envio que eu fiz ai?

Comment: Sim, e nem o nome vazio foi enviado dessa vez

Comment: @PublioElon como sabe que não foi enviado? Olhou pelo console do navegador? Não pode ser simplesmente que tua aplicação no heroku esteja errada do lado do back-end? Aliais em que linguagem vc fez isso?

Comment: eu estou com o link do servidor, onde retorna um get com os dados enviados, eu tentei usando ajax com jquery e foi, mas desta forma não vai mesmo, não entendi o porque ainda

Comment: @PublioElon blz, mas sem eu olhar o código eu realmente não tenho como adivinhar onde esta o erro, eu nem sei o que vc fez, não tem como eu dizer é em X que esta errado, consegue entender isso? Sabe o que é console do navegador? Já usou isso?

Comment: infelizmente nao tenho acesso ao código do servidor, de qualquer forma esse foi o erro que o console me passou "testar.html:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at testar.html:7"

Comment: @PublioElon é, mas ai eu só mudei um trecho do seu código pra explicar a parte do Ajax, isso ai é outro problema, inclusive que já respondi em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/207824/3635, basta usar `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { <codigo aqui dentro> });`, editei a resposta.

Comment: ah, agora mostrou certinho, só que to recebendo erro HTTP ou conexão: 0 ai no console Failed to load url do servidor: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access, e mesmo assim ele passou o espaço em branco

Comment: @PublioElon primeiro que vc provavelmente esta tentando acessar via protocolo `file:///`, para que funcione ambos devem estar no mesmo dominio, se o seu .html esta no seu computador e o site que quer acessar em outro dominio ai não tem como acessar né? Seria meio que falha de segurança se fosse possivel, quando ler uma mensagem de erro dá uma pesquisada no site, exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86342/cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resou

Comment: existe alguma forma privada de eu te enviar o link do container, pra vc dar uma olhada?

Comment: @PublioElon manda no meu email que esta no meu perfil aqui do site, mas não prometo nada, pq é como eu disse, não tem como burlar a segurança, os links que tem mandei já explicam o que tem que fazer, se vc não tem acesso a aplicação no heroku então não tem o que resolver, simplesmente é impossivel.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, acho que você poderia utilizar JQuery e fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var nome= $("#nome").val();

    $.post("caminho_da_serve", "&variavel=" + nome , function(result) {

    });
});
```