# Como fazer isso em JavaScript puro?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como eu faço isso em JS puro?

```
$(function () {
    $("#selCurso").change(function () {
        Pesquisar();
    });
});
```

Comment: Segue sugestão para o equivalente do `$.ready` (`$(function () {})`): [**Existe algum equivalente de “$(document).ready()” com Javascript puro?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137881/3635)

Answer (score 4):

`$()` é um *shorthand* de `jQuery()` que, por sua vez, é uma função que pode receber diferentes parâmetros e tomar uma decisão pra cada um deles.

No início, é passado como parâmetro toda a sua função. Isto serve para que a função só seja executada depois que todo o DOM já foi carregado e está pronto pra uso — [vide documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3).

O equivalente a isto, seria usar o evento `DOMContentLoaded` do documento.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { });
```

Você pode ler mais sobre isso em específico em **[Qual a diferença entre $(document).ready() e window.onload?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182797/18246)** e também em **[Existe algum equivalente de "$(document).ready()" com Javascript puro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137850/18246)**

No segundo caso, a função `$()` recebe um seletor e devolve um ou mais elementos que "atendam" a este seletor — [vide documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context).
Igual ao CSS, **`#selCurso`** é um seletor para o elemento que tiver o id igual a **selCurso**.

O equivalente a isto é **`document.getElementById('selCurso')`**.
Ou, de uma forma mais "moderna" **`document.querySelector('#selCurso')`**.

A função `change` adiciona um *event handler* ao evento JavaScript chamado "*change*".

O equivalente a isto é **`.addEventListener('change', callback)`**.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('selCurso').addEventListener('change', function () {
        Pesquisar();
    });
});
```