# document.getElementById('ID').func(....) vs ID.func(...)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Ontem deparei-me com uma [coisa curiosa](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107709/press-any-key-to-continue/107750#107750), não fazia ideia que dava para fazer desta maneira.

Até agora eu fazia da seguinte maneira:

```js
document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = 'CONTENT';
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
```

Sempre mas sempre vi a fazer assim, até que ontem reparei que:

```js
a.innerHTML = 'CONTENT';
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
```

Também funciona.

Claramente não se perde legibilidade, e uma grande vantagem é que não escrevemos tanto (`document.getElementById('...')`), podendo logo fazer diretamente referência ao elemento apenas com o id. Imagino que implicitamente a função `document.getElementById('...')` esteja a ser executada na mesma, mas:

Porque não se usa mais esta maneira? Pelo menos eu (que me lembre) nunca tinha visto.

Quais são as vantagens/desvantagens de uma em relação à outra? (se é que existe alguma)

Comment: Sempre tive essa dúvida, boa pergunta...

Comment: Obrigado @MagicHat, realmente nunca tinha reparado antes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basicamente é um problema de visibilidade. O que acontece se o seu `id` for uma propriedade do objeto `window`? Não sei se sabe, todas propriedades que você acessa globalmente ou estão em `window`.

O código da pergunta é o mesmo que:

```js
window.a.innerHTML = 'CONTENT';
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
```

Isso não é padrão. É algo que o Internet Explorer começou fazer (colocar os IDs do DOM dentro do objeto `window`), muito programador começou usar e outros navegadores se sentiram "obrigados" a manter compatibilidade. Mas não pode contar com isso.

Execute isto:

```js
top.innerHTML = 'CONTENT'; //top é uma propriedade de window
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/InnerHtml.js).

Então na maioria dos casos funcionará, mas em alguns não. Seja porque a implementação não aceita essa forma, seja porque vai confundir com algo do objeto. Não é melhor manter um estilo e usar só uma forma que funcionará sempre? Use a forma com [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) que é padrão, sempre será suportada em qualquer implementação do DOM conforme a especificação de HTML/EcmaScript.

Nunca foi intenção ter essa forma compacta acessando o ID diretamente. Embora pra falar a verdade, aqui vai um pouco de opinião, até deveria permitir isso, mas do jeito certo, no `document` e não no `window`, e os IDs serem segregados em uma propriedade específica para evitar a confusão com o objeto.

Essa técnica é para te dar um objeto local (espero que esteja usando um `var` ou `let`) que não se confunde com outras propriedades.

Eu acho que poderiam ter feito algo parecido com isso:

```
document.ids.a.innerHTML = 'CONTENT';
```

tem gente que acha que nem precisaria tudo isto e o `id` sozinho já deveria resolver e o programador que se vire para se houver conflito de nome com alguma propriedade. Faz algum sentido. Até poderia ter uma forma padrão na linguagem, tipo usar `#top` para não confundir com `top`.

Na verdade já acho errado `window` ser o objeto *default*. `document` é o que você mais usa.

Comment: Como seria um identificador no object window ?

Comment: @MagicHat não sei se entendi o que deseja saber. Pelo menos além do que já está mostrando na pergunta.

Comment: Quero dizer que não entendi, sua colocação em relação ao object window... Uma vez que os identificadores ao meu ver não estarão acima de document object (na verdade é minha crença), e sua colocação fez.questionar-me...

Comment: @MagicHat me desculpe, mas não estou entendendo qual é sua dúvida.

Comment: Tranquilo, assim como dito na resposta abaixo, cada vez que se define um id automaticamente é criado um elemento de acesso DOM, isto posto, não entendo a relação com o object window

Comment: @MagicHat editei, veja se ajudou alguma coisa.

Comment: Hum,. Creio que agora esclareceu, qnd se refere ao object window , vc quer dizer as propriedades e conflitos com essas propriedades, mas caso o id não conflite, tudo bem?

Comment: @MagicHat tudo bem, desde que use um navegador, ou outro mecanismo que use DOM desta forma, que trabalhe assim. Se pegar algum que não trabalhe, não vai funcionar. Acabou sendo raro ter algo assim, é improvável que alguém mude esse comportamento um dia, mas não é padrão.

Comment: Muito bom, Obgado, com teu exemplo de conflito entre propriedades/ids, fiquei esclarececido, também fazia ideia que pudesse haver falta de compatibilidade entre browsers para esta implementação

Comment: Só pra ter uma nota http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123098/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento dup?

Comment: @bigown creio que sim

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que o único motivo para não usar o elemento id direto é para evitar conflitos, pois todas as variáveis globais, incluindo os ids que são armazenados nos navegadores deixando essas informações "lotadas", por esse motivo está obsoleto seu uso preferindo o GetElementById  que faz o que diz pega o elemento pelo seu id.

Portanto, essa funcionalidade de recuperar o id direto pode ou não funcionar dependendo do seu navegador e a forma que gerencia essas "variáveis globais".

Comment: Uma coisa que nunca foi oficializado não pode ser [deprecado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178138/101).