# O que o JavaScript pega como padrão?

Tags: javascript

Exemplo, tenho o `window.location.href`, o `location.href`, o `document.location.href`

Esse segundo no caso, o que o JavaScript vai deixar como padrão? o Window? Padrão digo, posso usar tanto o window quanto o document, então, como não coloco nada, ele pega qual? Ou existe diferença dos 3 comandos?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179468/101

Answer (score 2):

`window.location` é um objeto que matém toda informação sobre a location atual do documento (host, href, portas, protocolos, etc.)

`document.location` é um sinônimo do `window.location`, mas está deprecated há um bom tempo. Não use este.

`location.href` é a forma abreviada de `window.location.href` (se você chama local do objeto global - `window`, então isso é `window.location.href`), e no fim das contas isso é apenas uma string com a url completa do website.

Fontes

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: Pode citar as fontes que baseiam suas afirmações?

Comment: Está um pouco ambíguo qual não deve ser usada mais.

Comment: Edições feitas com fonte e tirando ambiguidade