# Jquery - Melhor forma de selecionar o mesmo elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

Meu sistema funciona na forma de SPA (Aplicação de Única Página), faço o carregamento de todas as funções que irei usar no sistema em um unico arquivo(Que é leve por sinal), o problema é que é o seguinte, toda vez que faço o load de uma pagina, eu preciso resgatar os inputs com o Jquery, a minha duvida é a seguinte:
 Não vou estar sobrecarregando o navegador chamando diversas vezes o mesmo elemento no Jquery?

Aqui está um exemplo do meu codigo:

```
var editContact = function(){
    $("#element").mask();
    //Call Google Maps
}
```

Arquivo que vai ser carregado diversas vezes pelo jQuery.load();

```
<script>
    new editContact();
</script>

<input id="#element">
```

Eu estaria sobrecarregando o sistema, toda vez que faço o load na pagina, já que eu chamo a função editContact() toda vez?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Não vou estar sobrecarregando o navegador chamando diversas vezes o mesmo elemento no Jquery?*

Não necessariamente, dependendo da complexidade do projeto, neste específico caso penso que é desnecessário utilizar o código desta maneira.

O que acontece quando o código `new editContact();` é executado:

1. Um novo objeto é criado, herdando de `editContact`.
2. A função do construtor `editContact` é chamada com os argumentos
   especificados, e com isso ligado ao objeto recém-criado. O novo `editContact` é
   equivalente ao novo `editContact()`, ou seja, se nenhuma lista de argumento é
   especificado, `editContact` é chamado sem argumentos.
3. O objeto retornado pela função do construtor torna-se o resultado de
   toda a nova expressão. Se a função do construtor não retornar
   explicitamente um objeto, o objeto criado na 1ª etapa é usado em vez
   disso. Normalmente, os construtores não retornam um valor, mas podem
   optar por fazê-lo se quiserem substituir o processo normal da
   criação do objeto. <sub>([Ler mais sobre o operador `new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new))</sub>

### Existem melhores práticas ou formas de abordar isto?

A meu ver, acho que podias simplesmente fazer isto:

```js
(function () {
    // $('#element').mask();
    alert('Olá Mundo!');
})();
```

### Ou

```js
function editContact() {
    // $('#element').mask();
    alert('Olá Mundo!');
}
editContact(); // irá executar a função automaticamente
```

Que ambas as maneiras irão executar as funções quando a página estiver pronta (equivalente a [`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)). A única diferença é que na segunda opção podes reutilizar esta mesma função em outros lugares, como por exemplo:

```js
function editContact() {
    // $(this).mask();
    $('#resultado').html('resultado do input: '+ $('#element').val());
}
editContact(); // executa a função quando a página estiver pronta

// Abaixo, quando o elemento é modificado ou despois de carregar em uma tecla...
$(document).on('change keyup', '#element', function () {
    editContact(); // chama a função
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="element">
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: O problema é que essa parte: "<input id="element">
<div id="resultado"></div>" não está no documento ainda, pois ela vai ser carregada futuramente quando o usuário clicar no link.

Comment: Meu index seria algo assim: <body><div class="page"></div></body> e sempre que o usuário clica em outra pagina ela carrega essa pagina editcontact.php e chama essa função no jQuery

Comment: Se for uma **outra página diferente**, então o script será carregado da mesma maneira, pois ele está para ser executado quando a página estiver pronta. Se é uma **plataforma apenas de uma única página** podes acionar  a `.mask()` quando o `click` para chamar a outra secção acontece. Ou então usar o ultimo exemplo que postei, que irá criar o `.mask()` (até mesmo para elementos criados dinamicamente) quando alguma coisa no input mudar ou uma tecla é primada `$(document).on('change keyup'...` . Por isso que já pus aí de propósito esse exemplo

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado CHUN

Answer (score -1):

A função jQuery `$` faz uma busca na página sempre, e sim, essa busca pode ser demorada dependendo de como sua página é formada.

Uma alternativa para não utilizá-la é usar `window.element` ou `window['element']` onde está ***element*** é o `id` do elemento que você deseja.
Os browsers modernos criam variáveis de referência para os seus elementos.

Comment: Olá Matheus, dá uma olhada aqui acerca de usar `window['id_do_elemento']`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123106/129 Eu desaconselho essa prática.

Comment: ok, obrigado pela dica.