# Resgatar nome do input file e atribuir input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código com um `<input>` do tipo texto e outro do tipo arquivo. Vejam:

```html
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Name file:
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br/><br/>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
</form>
```

Gostaria de preencher o *input text* com o nome do arquivo carregado no *input file*. Qual melhor forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes ir buscar o nome do ficheiro a `.files[0].name`, depois é só preencher o input de texto com esse valor:

```js
var inputNome = document.getElementById('name');
var inputFicheiro = document.getElementById('file');

inputFicheiro.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var nome = this.files[0].name;
  inputNome.value = nome;
});
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Name file:
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br/><br/>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é a melhor, mas com jQuery é possível recuperar os arquivos pelo evento *change*:

```js
$('[name="file"]').on('change', function(){
  $('[name="name"]').val($(this)[0].files[0].name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Name file:
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" readonly><br/><br/>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Busque pelo elemento do tipo `file` em seu formulário e armazene o `name` dele em uma variável, em seguida atribua ao `value` do input do tipo `text`.

Se você definir um `name` para seu formulário, você não precisara selecionar o `input` do tipo `text` com `querySelector`, simplesmente use: 
`document.formName.fieldName`.

```
var inputFicheiro = document.getElementById('file');

inputFicheiro.addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.formName.name.value = this.files[0].name;
  // Como seu input text tem o name de "name" utilize da mesma maneira.
});


<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formName">
   Name file:
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br/><br/>
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
</form>
```

Comment: Rafael, acerca de usar `document.formName.name`, desaconselho, aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123106/129

Comment: obrigado @Sergio