# Script não funciona no IE mas funciona nos outros navegadores

Tags: javascript, jquery

Script não funciona no IE mas funciona normalmente nos outros navegadores, o erro ocorre em: `jQuery(central).prop("disabled", false);` e a mensagem que recebo é:

> SCRIPT5009: 'central' não está definido.

Já tentei `.prop` e `.attr`.

JavaScript:

```js
function carregarCentrais() {
  if (jQuery("#selectEmissor").val() != -1) {
    jQuery(central).prop("disabled", false);
    central.setAttribute('class', 'input g270');
    jQuery("select#central option").remove();
    var selectCentral = jQuery('#central');
    jQuery("#central").val(-1);
    if (jQuery("#selectEmissor").val() != null) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "preencheCentrais.do",
        data: 'selectEmissor=' + jQuery("#selectEmissor").val(),
        success: function(listaCentrais) {
          jQuery.each(listaCentrais, function(i, central) {
            selectCentral.append('<option value="' + central.codigo + '">' + central.descricao + '</option>');
          });
          jQuery("select#central").prepend("<option value='-1' selected='selected'></option>");
        },
        error: function() {
          alert("Erro ao pesquisar central pelo emissor");
        }
      });
    }
  } else {
    central.setAttribute('class', 'input g270 read-only');
    jQuery("select#central option").remove();
    jQuery(central).prop("disabled", true);
  }
  sucursal.setAttribute('class', 'input g270 read-only');
  jQuery("select#sucursal option").remove();
  jQuery(sucursal).prop("disabled", true);
}
```

HTML:

```
<td>
    <springform:select id="central" class="input g270 read-only" path="extratoLancamento.central" value="${form.extratoLancamento.central}" onchange="carregarSucursais();" style="width: 250px;" disabled="true"></springform:select>
</td>
```

Comment: E o que deveria ser `central`? Ele não está definido no código.

Comment: está, eu só não coloquei, vou fazer um edit, mas enfim funciona nos outros navegadores, porém no IE não

Comment: Mas deveria ser uma variável `central` ou é o elemento `#central`? Ali você colocou a definição de `#central`. No Spring é a mesma coisa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em alguns browsers pode aceder-se a elementos diretamente com o `id`, ou seja: havendo um elemento com `id` "central" ele pode ser acedido como uma variável global `window.central`. Isso é muito má ideia ([já falei sobre isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123106/129)) e alguns browsers bloqueiam isso.

Em vêz de `jQuery(central)` deves usar `jQuery('#central')` que é um seletor CSS de `id` válido e vai selecionar o elemento que tens com esse `id`.