# Erro no onclick

Tags: javascript

Tenho um formulário do qual chamo a função **mesmoEmail()** no evento onclick.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="MesmoEmail" value="S" id="mesmoEmail" onclick="mesmoEmail();"> Mesmo e-mail do cadastro
```

E o Javascript está dessa forma:

```
<script>
function mesmoEmail(){
  alert('aqui');
  var marcado = document.getElementById('mesmoEmail');
}
</script>
```

O problema é que não está funcionado e no console aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no código fonte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aqui quando coloquei o código, a palavra **Mesmo** fica de outra cor. Não estou conseguindo identificar o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifiquei o erro. O ID tem o mesmo nome da função no onclick, então fiz a seguinte alteração:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mesmoEmail" value="S" id="mesmoEmail" onclick="mesmoEmail();"> Mesmo e-mail do cadastro
```

Para:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="MesmoEmail" value="S" id="mesmoemail" onclick="mesmoEmail();"> Mesmo e-mail do cadastro
```

Comment: Ops, coloquei uma resposta e não vi que tinha respondido. haha

Comment: Uma outra pergunta sobre este problema de como as IDs podem causar problemas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123106/129

Answer (score 1):

Podes simplificar desta forma:

```js
function mesmoEmail(el){
  var marcado = el.value;
  console.log(marcado);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="MesmoEmail" value="S" id="mesmoEmail" onclick="mesmoEmail(this);"> Mesmo e-mail do cadastro
```