# nao funciona quando coloca no form onchange javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function teste(valor)
{
    if( valor=="novo" )
    {
        document.getElementById('quantdependente').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('quantdependente').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
#quantdependente {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form id="formulario" name="formulario" action="montadependente.php" method="post">
    <select name="teste" id="teste" onchange="teste( this.value );">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="novo">novo</option>
    </select>
    <div id="quantdependente" name="quantdependente">
      <input type="number" value="" step="1">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="btenviar" value="enviar">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta? O código aparentemente funciona. Pode acrescentar uma descrição detalhista do seu problema?

Comment: @AugustoVasques ao testar o código no Chrome ocorre o erro `Uncaught TypeError: teste is not a function`, isto porque ele criou um elemento com o `id="teste"`, o que conflita com a função chamada `function teste(valor)`, pois é algo comum em navegador usarem IDs do DOM como variaveis globais do objeto `window.`, como foi explicado em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123098/3635

Answer (score 2):

Tente adicionar um evento ao elemento, acredito que seja a melhor opção

```js
function teste() {
 valor = this.value;

 console.log( 'mudou para: '+ valor )

  if( valor == 'novo' ) {
  document.getElementById('quantdependente').style.display = 'block';
 } else {
  document.getElementById('quantdependente').style.display = 'none';
 }
}
document.getElementById('teste').addEventListener('change', teste);
```

```css
#quantdependente {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form id="formulario" name="formulario" action="montadependente.php" method="post">
    <select name="teste" id="teste" >
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="novo">novo</option>
    </select>
    <div id="quantdependente" name="quantdependente">
      <input type="number" value="" step="1">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="btenviar" value="enviar">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Esse é um comportamento peculiar do navegador. Dentro dos eventos de cada elemento como `onclick` e `onchange`, algumas variáveis são inicializadas implicitamente pelo navegador, como as variáveis `event`, `arguments`, e uma outra variável como o mesmo id do elemento, no seu caso, `teste`.

Você tem um elemento e uma função com o nome `teste`, e dentro do `onchange` daquele elemento, `teste` se refere ao elemento, não a função, por isso invocar `teste( this.value )` resulta num erro, pois `teste` não é uma função. Repare que o código funciona se a função tiver outro nome:

```js
function testeFunc(valor) {
    console.log('Função foi invocada recebendo o valor', valor)
}
```

```css
#quantdependente {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form id="formulario" name="formulario" action="montadependente.php" method="post">
    <select name="teste" id="teste" onchange="testeFunc( this.value );">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="novo">novo</option>
    </select>
    <div id="quantdependente" name="quantdependente">
      <input type="number" value="" step="1">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="btenviar" value="enviar">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sua explicação é muito coerente. Sabes dizer se há/existe documentação a respeito ... fiquei curioso?

Comment: Desculpe Lauro, não conheço documentação sobre isso. Aprendi sobre essas variáveis no SO americano.